# How to disable zipfinger packaging tool in Android Studio 3.6.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I downloaded Android Studio 3.6 RC3 which uses a new packaging tool called `zipfinger` build APK. I wanted to try it out but now I'm facing some issues when I load my old projects. It would be better if I can disable it for my project. How can I disable it and use the old packaging tool?

Answer (score 0):

> Zipfinger is a new packaging tool that builds APKs which should provide speed improvements. But if you're facing any issue and you want to disable it then you can do it easily by adding `useNewApkCreator` property in `build.gradle`.

Open your `app/build.gradle` file and add the following:

```
android {
    ...
    useNewApkCreator = false
}
```

Comment: They seem to have changed it in AGP 3.6.0.
I get:
Could not set unknown property 'useNewApkCreator' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: The docs now say:
 You can revert to using the old packaging tool by including the following in your gradle.properties file:

android.useNewApkCreator=false

Comment: Did not work, can't use it in project's build.gradle, app build.gradle. Have tried put it in gradle.propertties and via parameter -Pandroid.useNewApkCreator=false, still got IllegalStateException "too many entries", caused by zipflinger, the only fix now only to use gradle 4.1.0-alpha

Comment: Ran into issue where `android.useNewApkCreator=false` is not working in the `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add to **gradle.properties** file according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin):

```
android.useNewApkCreator = false
```